# What is MYSQL Query to display the sequence number that reset when new value on next row?

Tags: mysql

i have table schemes like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `hobby` (
`hobbyid` int(50) NOT NULL,
`hobbyname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`hobbyid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `hobby` (`hobbyid`, `hobbyname`) VALUES
(1, 'walk'),
(2, 'music'),
(3, 'playing'),
(4, 'shopping');

CREATE TABLE `kids` (
 `nameid` int(50) NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `kids` (`nameid`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Ashley'),
(2, 'Bob'),
(3, 'Lucy');

CREATE TABLE `kidshobby` (
  `nameid` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `hobbyid` int(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `kidshobby` (`nameid`, `hobbyid`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 1);
```

what I try to accomplish is to display result like this:

```
Seq    Name
1      Ashley
2      Ashley
1      Bob
1      Lucy
```

which Column Seq will produce sequence increment number from 1 and will reset if has new name.

What is MYSQL Query to produce that?

please the answer only in mysql query script because this job from my boss may only done by MySQL Script. I have search in all forum i couldnt find it. I only can produce sequence row

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "assignment"? is this homework?

Comment: No.. what i mean is i have to (what do i call i lack in english grammar ). I work in kids education area and that is assignment from my boss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get your result by session variable. Try This query hope this will work for you

```
SET @sec := 0;
SET @name := null;
SELECT seq, name from (
    SELECT IFNULL(@name,@name := k.name), 
    IF(@name <> k.name, @sec := 1, @sec := @sec+1) ,
    IF(@name <> k.name, @name := k.name, ''), 
    @sec AS seq, k.name AS name FROM kids k 
    LEFT JOIN kidshobby kh 
    ON kh.nameid = k.nameid  
    JOIN hobby h 
    ON kh.hobbyid = h.hobbyid 
    ORDER BY name
) AS temp;
```

Comment: hi vipin thx for responding.how if I add another 3 lucy. lucy walk, lucy music and lucy playing. I try your query but column Seq becomes NULL

Comment: @Devisy hi devisy i have added three column in  kidshobby table `INSERT INTO  `kidshobby` (  `nameid` ,  `hobbyid` ) 
VALUES ( 3, 2 ) , ( 3, 3 ) , ( 3, 4 );` and then run my own query output is correct.
OUTPUT is 
`seq name  
1 Ashley
2 Ashley
1 Bob
2 Bob
1 Lucy
2 Lucy
3 Lucy
4 Lucy`

Comment: @Devisy hi devisy you can see this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/990090/1/1

Comment: hi vipin im glad u reply again.  ur link keep showing Loading build schema

Comment: hey vipin youre right. im doing my own mistake. very thankful of this

Comment: hi vipin i see there is sec and seq. that was on purpose you make them different? can u explain

Comment: helo vipin now i understand thank you. youre great. very best!

Comment: @Devisy its my pleasure :)